# Primefaces: Keep value of input text inside a dialog after calling initPosition

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a dialog which need to be rerender after a certain selectOneMenu ist chosen.

To accomplish that, the following code is used inside the selectOneMenu:

```
<p:ajax event="valueChange" oncomplete="PF('dialog').initPosition();" update="panelGrid" />
```

However, after the dialog is rerendered, all user inputs in my `p:inputText`are lost (reset to value from java bean).

How can I make the inputText keep the new value without persisting it to backend?

Comment: can you add your managedbean and also the html form where p:ajax is placed and html form where the p:dialog resides.. add as much as possible. Based on what u gave i cannot advise anything

Comment: Are you saying that the input fields are not covered by `update="panelGrid"`? If they however are, why are you not updating only the dialog itself, but also apparently unnecessarily the input fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

provide the XHTML page where your inputText component is situated. My best guess to solve your problem is by adding the p:ajax component inside the inputText component. `p:ajax` as defined below triggers on the default event which is **change** and processes @this which is the inputText component. this way it saves your input on the backing bean as soon as you exit the field.

```
 <p:inputText value="#{bean.value}" >
     <p:ajax />
 </p:inputText>
```